# C++ string of a specific length

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm trying to write a function that has a concept of a "serial number".  It has a specific length.  I'm hoping to simplify the constructors by creating a new type called SerialNumber that wraps this concept of a 13-byte number.  For instance, I don't want a Product(const char* m) or Product(const std::string& str) that will truncate the value and be counter-intuitive.  It'd prefer Product(const SerialNumber& sn) that I can always count on as the correct length.  What's the best way to do this?  Should it a a typedef for char[13] or is there a way to do this with the string class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a constructor which accepts a std::string, and then within your constructor verify that the length is indeed 13. If it's not, simply throw an exception -- that's why they exist. Keep in mind that a char[13] won't guarantee that the string is 13 characters long, after all it could be "hi", followed by 11 null terminators.

Comment: As an alternative if exceptions feel too "permanent", you could use an assert which you could turn off at a later point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for your case, but one option is to still use std::string but for example `Product`'s constructor would throw if the string was the wrong length. Otherwise the simplest approach seems to be a wrapper `SerialNumber` class for `std::string` (or `char[14]`, but I'm hesitant to use C-strings in C++ code).

Answer (score 0):

I would use either a typedef char[13] or a wrapping class around char[13]. Since a table of chars is the same as a char*, you will easily be able to convert it to std::string if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following

```
struct SerialNumber {
    static bool TryCreate(const std::string& data, std::auto_ptr<SerialNumber>& ptr) {
        if (data.length() != 13) {
            ptr.reset();
            return false;
        } else {
            ptr.reset(new SerialNumber(data.c_str()));
            return true;
        }
    }

private:
    SerialNumber(const char* data) {
        memcpy(m_data, data, sizeof(data));
    }

    char m_data[13];
};
```

Comment: @Donotalo, nothing. The OP said the need was just for the 13 `char` values so I didn't want to waste the extra overhead of `string`.